# What should I do if my mongodb document gets too large?

Tags: mongodb

What should I do if my mongodb document gets too large? The query is slowing down too much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR0l0.jpg)

Comment: Here is a troubleshooting to fix the slow query: https://medium.com/@igorkhomenko/troubleshooting-mongodb-100-cpu-load-and-slow-queries-da622c6e1339

Comment: the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/) provides some strategies to address slow queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharding to distribute your data across multiple machines, it will improve your read/write performance over large data sets.

Please refer MongoDB's official documentation for more help regarding sharding .

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking large documents are an anti-pattern in NoSQL because they force the system to read and write large amounts of data when often times the application really only needs a small subset of the data in the document.  The best practice is to create items that are reasonably sized and use indexes to query for them.

One example might be to create items for Customers, Orders and Invoices then tag all of those items with CustomerId and OrderId.  Create a compound index on those two attributes and now you can efficiently query for all the orders a customer has made and the invoices for those orders.

In the above example creating a single item for a customer that contained all orders would cause the system to read and write the entire order history of the customer every time an order is placed or updated.

All that being said, if you do need to query for huge blobs that are larger than 16MB then just link them together with a tag attribute and index that attribute.  Create a tag called BlobId, index it and then query for all items with the same BlobId.